# Flex space-between 2 items, but centered when wrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

#### What I would like to do

Consider two elements in a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Thing 1</div>
    <div>Other thing</div>
</div>
```

I would like the following criteria to be met:

- In a wide context, the two elements should be at opposite ends of the container.
- In a narrow context, such that the two elements won't fit in a single row, the second element should 'wrap' onto a new line.
- In a context where the elements are on two rows, both elements should be centred.

In addition, I would like to avoid using media breakpoints, so that the layout will work irrespective of the widths of the elements and/or the container. The solution doesn't need to use flex-box (it's just easier to explain what I want in terms of flex-box).

#### My attempts

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This works for the first two criteria, but not the third. I've experimented with different values of `justify-content`/`flex-grow`/`flex-basis` but have not been able to find a winning combination.

I've also thought about using `grid` but had equally little success.

#### Note

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718872/flexbox-justify-content-center-but-space-between-on-flex-wrap) is a very similar question (although, a more specific use-case since I only require 2 elements rather than a general solution.)

Comment: You can't. CSS can't detect wrapping. You need media queries

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. I do appreciate this. Nonetheless, I have seen clever tricks (arguably hacks) that achieve what I had thought impossible with CSS before now. I may well very be over-optimistic here, but I live in hope :)

Comment: If we could this would still be a duplicate of the link you provided and the answer would be posted there.

Comment: @Paulie_D Perhaps. A solution to the linked question would certainly be a solution to this question, however the other way round doesn't follow. I was imagining maybe something along the lines of an additional div, with a high `flex-grow` value to emulate the `space-between` behaviour. This doesn't quite work. But such a solution could potentially be a solution to this question, but not the linked one.

Comment: @Paulie_D Also, the solutions that are linked in the 'closed question report' do not apply here since I can't use media-queries. I have clarified this in an edit under the 'Note' sub-heading.

Comment: Unfortunately, media queries are the answer. You will have to adjust your methodology.

Comment: @Paulie_D media queries are of no use when you don't know the size of the container. Even if this wasn't the case, this is what the questions asks for. There are always java-script solutions. And the java-script solution for a 2-item case would be considerably simpler than in the linked question (which requires a general case). As such this is a different question, since it requires a considerably different answer. I have also found a pure CSS solution, which doesn't use media queries. It will work for this case, but not in the general case. This question should be reopened.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411611).

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question into a different question is against policy when doing so invalidates one or more answers, even if the original question isn't what you really intended to ask. Your edit here invalidated an answer. Users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I've reverted your edit. You're *encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps linking this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @Makyen, the question that is linked in the Closed notice does not provide an answer to this question. I arrived at this question from a Google Search as it matched what I was looking for, i.e. a way to center wrapped items within a flex container when `justify-content` is set to `space-between`. The linked question (Center buttons on wrap only) doesn't help with this at all - the `space-between` requirement is quite specific. I'm confused as to what was poor about this question and am strongly considering asking something very similar.

Comment: @Luke The question was discussed on Meta Stack Overflow, but you can't see that question, as it was deleted about a year ago by the author. While some clarifying edits could have been made here, those edits would have at least partially invalidated the existing answer. I would have preferred to see a better Q&A pair, but we, mostly, land on the side of preserving existing content when making a ruling on such issues. It would have been possible to create a new question which clearly differentiated itself from this question and the, mostly, duplicate. The question author was encouraged to do so.

Comment: @Luke As to matching your situation, I note this question doesn't have a requirement to use `space-between`, or even a flexbox. Thus, even if the changes had been allowed here, it wouldn't have exactly matched your requirement to use `justify-content: space-between`. If using that isn't an actual, hard requirement, I'd suggest any question you might write state the *functional requirements*, rather than making how you think it might be implemented part of the hard requirements (e.g. the question OP here offered a solution which used `justify-content: center` in a now-deleted answer).

Comment: @Makyen, this question's title reads, *"**Flex** **`space-between`** 2 items, but centered when wrapped"* (emphasis mine) - this specifies both flexbox and space-between. Am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: @Luke I'd suggest you read the body of the question, which says "The solution doesn't need to use flex-box (it's just easier to explain what I want in terms of flex-box)." This was further confirmed as the author's intent by the author posting an answer which used `justify-content: center;` I agree, and have always agreed, that the question body and title could and should be clarified. Overall, it was quite unfortunate that the initial version of the question wasn't clear as to what the OP wanted and that an answer was posted that, effectively, locked the question to what had been answered.

Comment: @Makyen yes I had read the question and noted that the OP had "opened" it up for alternative solutions - I generally think the title should be the authority on the scope of the question. Thanks for taking the time to further explain your reasoning behind closing. It's helpful for me to understand this and I can see how this one ended up being a "muddy" issue. Unfortunate as you've said.

Answer (score -2):

With `justify-content: space-around` you can achieve the 3rd criteria with elements present at opposite end in wide context

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Thing 1</div>
    <div>Other thing</div>
</div>
```

Else if you want them to present at extreme end in wide context then have to use `@media` , this depend on the width of text-div's which makes them wrap after a certain reduce in view port width .

Here will take 500px width where text will wrap for demo only

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .textDiv {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textDiv">Thing 1</div>
  <div class="textDiv">Other thing</div>
</div>
```